If $xy \in \mathbb{C}(u,v)$, then there exists $w$ such that $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(xy,w)$
Let $R=\mathbb{C}(u,v) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$, with $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$.
Denote $n:=\deg_{1,1}(u)$ and $m:=\deg_{1,1}(v)$, where $\deg_{1,1}$ means the total degree of the given two-dimensional polynomial.
Since each of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ and $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ is of transcendence degree two over $\mathbb{C}$, we have $\mathbb{C}(u,v) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is algebraic and finite dimensional, so $d:=[\mathbb{C}(x,y):\mathbb{C}(u,v)]  < \infty$.
Further assume that:

$d \geq 2$, so $\mathbb{C}(u,v) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
$xy \in \mathbb{C}(u,v)$.


Question: Is it possible to find $w \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that
$\mathbb{C}(xy,w)=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$?

Remarks:
(1) $u=xy, v=x+y$; here $w=v=x+y$ (and $d=2$).
(2) $u=x^2+y^2, v=x+y$; this is the same field as in (1), the symmetric functions w.r.t. the exchange involution $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$. Of course, we can take $w=v=x+y$.
(3) $u=x^3y,v=x^2$; It is clear that $\mathbb{C}(x^3y,x^2)=\mathbb{C}(xy,x^2)$ (for example, $\frac{u}{v}=xy$), so we can take $w=x^2$. Here, $d=2$, indeed: $\mathbb{C}(xy,x^2)(y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ and the minimal polynomial of $y$ over $\mathbb{C}(xy,x^2)$ is $f(T)=x^2T^2-(xy)^2$.
(4) $u=x^3+y^3, v=x+y$. We have $v^3-u=(x+y)^3-(x^3+y^3)=3x^2y+3xy^2=3xy(x+y)$, so $\frac{v^3-u}{3(x+y)}=xy$, therefore $xy \in \mathbb{C}(u,v)$, so this is again (1).
Thank you very much!

Actually, there is no need to assume that $d \geq 2$. For $d=1$, we have $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, hence $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(xy,x)$ (or $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(xy,y)$), so we can take $w=x$ or $w=y$ (and there are additional options for $w$).
